404 for all pages in wordpress multisite after migration
I am getting 404 page (not apache) for all the pages in wordpress multisite including home page. I have tried updating permalinks and changing file permissions, but still I am getting this 404 error.

Check .htaccess files and also replace database old links with new links.


Please check if the SSL have been installed for the website, There is chance of getting the 404 error if there is issue with the SSL.
Check if the DNS are pointing correctly and is propagating for the same.
You can also try by checking enabling the debug for the site.


If there was an issue with the SSL then OP's browser would show a different error and not even load the actual page/domain
